# Can I create custom element of the application with lazy loading modules?

Tags: angular

In Angular, I have one application in which app.module use lazy loading to load child modules and I want to use that angular application as a custom element so I can use as an external component to other application.

I know the custom elements can be created in separate application with app-root and replace it with our element  but when I want whole application with lazy load modules, it will not work like not identify modules on run time when referring as a custom element.

To understand what is custom element please refer below link:
https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: you want to convert lazy loaded component to angular elements right? so that you can use that custom angular element to any web application.

Comment: I have an application with root module but others are lazy modules and when I convert it to the custom element it will not understand other modules to load when I refer it to other application.

Comment: You are not turning an ANGULAR APPLICATION into an element. That is not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For loading children, use `loadChildren` in route path and `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`

route ex.

```
 { path: 'upload', loadChildren: './upload-image/upload-image.module#UploadImageModule' }
```

Comment: I know how to lazy load but do you know custom element? how we do routing in other application and integrate to work custom element as an external component?

Comment: what do you mean by other application? is that angular application or another framework.

Comment: other angular application. to understand well please search custom element in angular or refere this link https://angular.io/guide/elements

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is to create a library that can be usable as an npm dependency (for instance) in other applications.

Angular CLI has all the command lines you need for that.

Here is an easy [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).

Comment: I want a whole lazy loaded module in application to work as a custom element.